# Circuit drawing software

Tags: schematics, software

Does anyone recognize the software in whitch these circuits were drawn?[image]

Comment: If it's from a textbook it may be a generic graphics program like Corel Draw (or Inkscape).  If it's from an old enough textbook it may be really nice hand-drawing.

Comment: Could be _M4 Macros for Electric Circuit Diagrams in LATEX Documents_ by Dwight Aplevich

Comment: The infinity symbol does look like TeX. Might be worth asking on the TeX stackexchange. There are some example of the infinity symbol on it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133932/how-do-i-type-the-infinity-symbol-in-mactex .

Comment: @DDuck The symbols [look different](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html).